# Is it possible to develop a DNN Module with an inner Pane?

Tags: c#, module, dotnetnuke

Is it possible to develop a DNN module that allows other modules to be dropped into it?

In other words I would like to put "Panes" in my module and have them work basically the same way as they would if the Panes were contained in the skin.

Is this possible?  If so, are there any samples, articles, or documents that would help?

Side Note:  I currently develop modules using Chistoc's Module Development Template.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the panes setup in your module, you could use Page.LoadControl method to load the controls into your panes. In your modules settings, you can specify which modules you want in which pane and get the path to the control from DNN or have the user select which module and which module control to load.

For instance, heres an example with only one panel that I've done before:

ASCX

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
```

CODE BEHIND

```
var moduleView = new UserControl();
var userControl = moduleView.LoadControl("~/DesktopModules/PropertyInfoModule/ViewPropertyInfoModule.ascx");
pnlPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(userControl);
```